# Reading SequenceFile into RDD in Spark Results in imbalance Task

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

I have generated a sequence file which is about 900MB that contains 15 records, among them, the size of 13 records are around 64MB(The block size of our HDFS).

In Pyspark, I read it as follows (The key and value are both custom java class):

`rdd = sc.sequenceFile("hdfs:///Test.seq", keyClass = "ChunkID", valueClass="ChunkData", keyConverter="KeyToChunkConverter", valueConverter="DataToChunkConverter")`

`rdd.getNumPartitions()` shows that there are 14 partitions. And I try to perform some algorithm with it as follows:

```
def open_map():
    def open_map_nested(key_value):
        try:
            # ChunkID, ChunkData 
            key, data = key_value

            ####Algorithm Ommited#####                   

            if key[0] == 0:               
                return [['if', 'if', 'if']] 
            else:
                return [["else","else","else"]]
        except Exception, e:
            logging.exception(e)
            return [["None","None","None"],["None","None","None"]] #["None"]
    return open_map_nested
result = rdd.flatMap(open_map()).count()
```

However, when I open the Spark UI, the first two records are always assigned to one task as following diagram shows(also the input size is strange):
[image: inputsplit]
This results in other tasks which contain exactly one records waiting for the task to complete and becomes the bottleneck.
[image: execution time]
I have also tried to use java to implement the same function, however, the problem remains.

The setting of my job is  `--master yarn --deploy-mode client --driver-memory 8G --num-executors 20  --executor-cores 1 --executor-memory 1500M`.

---

My questions are:

- Is there any standard way to read sequencefile into RDD in spark?
- Is there any parameter that can avoid spark assign two records to the first task?

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated!!